# Async job in ansible with parallel poll

Tags: ansible

I am working on ansible-playbook which has multiple async tasks in it. My ansible polls the task1 after x amount of time and next to task2 and till last job one by one. Is there way , we can have more number of forks checking multiple asycn tasks in parallel ? - Basically i want to combine asycn + parallel. I am using ansible - 2.6.4

Answer (score 0):

we can use "strategy: free" in this case, at the beginning of the playbook...
with this option each host will run the playbook independently, irrespective of the other hosts...by default the strategy option is set to linear....in which all hosts will run each task before any host starts the next task, using the number of forks (default 5) to parallelize.....we can also refer to this official ansible document....

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same and here's what I came up with.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    # Create an empty array to store job ids
    - set_fact:
        job_ids: []

    # Do a thing .....
    - name: Sleep for thirty seconds
      command: sleep 30
      async: 1000
      poll: 0
      register: _action

    # Add the job ID to action_array
    - set_fact:
        job_ids: "{{ job_ids + [_action.ansible_job_id] }}"

    # Do something else ...
    - name: Sleep for one minute
      command: sleep 60
      async: 1000
      poll: 0
      register: _action
    
    # Also add this job ID to job_ids array
    - set_fact:
        action_array: "{{ job_ids + [_action.ansible_job_id] }}"

    # Let's take a look at what we have
    - debug:
        var: job_ids

    # Wait until all jobs have complete
    - name: wait all tasks to finish
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ a_job_id }}"
      register: job_result
      until: job_result.finished
      retries: 80
      delay: 15
      loop: "{{ job_ids }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: a_job_id
        label: "Job {{ a_job_id }} has completed"
```

Here's my terminal output from the playbook above

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Sleep for thirty seconds] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Sleep for one minute] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "action_array": [
        "181666307608.2006658",
        "227123662413.2006687"
    ]
}
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (80 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (79 retries left).

TASK [wait all tasks to finish] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=Job 181666307608.2006658 has completed)
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (80 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (79 retries left).
changed: [localhost] => (item=Job 227123662413.2006687 has completed)

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
pipenv run ansible-playbook temp.yml  7.21s user 0.64s system 12% cpu 1:03.97 total    PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Sleep for thirty seconds] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Sleep for one minute] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "action_array": [
        "181666307608.2006658",
        "227123662413.2006687"
    ]
}
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (80 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (79 retries left).

TASK [wait all tasks to finish] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=Job 181666307608.2006658 has completed)
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (80 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: wait all tasks to finish (79 retries left).
changed: [localhost] => (item=Job 227123662413.2006687 has completed)

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
pipenv run ansible-playbook temp.yml  7.21s user 0.64s system 12% cpu 1:03.97 total
```

Hope this helps someone!